Setting up Google AI Assistant SDK on Raspberry Pi 4
I have followed the guidelines from https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python on how to set up Google AI Assistant SDK's and am trying to get it working on my Raspberry Pi 4. I have followed all steps accurately as far as I can see. However, when I am told to run the following sample code (with the project id and model id replaced by my project info):
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id  --device-model-id
I encounter the following error:
/home/pi/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py:163: UserWarning: Global variable 'stderr' in cdef(): for consistency with C it should have a storage class specifier (usually 'extern')
warnings.warn("Global variable '%s' in cdef(): for consistency "
/home/theaustingelatt/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cffi/cparser.py:163: UserWarning: Global variable '__stderrp' in cdef(): for consistency with C it should have a storage class specifier (usually 'extern')
warnings.warn("Global variable '%s' in cdef(): for consistency "
Error: no such option: --project-id
I used the --help option and did not see --project-id listed as a viable option. However, this is confusing because I watched multiple tutorials all done in the same fashion work perfectly fine.
I also tried to run: googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --demo. However, the same error: no such option: --demo was populated.
I double and triple checked the documentation for the API setup and Actions Console setup and those appear to be in order.
Any help is appreciated!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
